# Как узнать версии зависимостей, используемые в Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot

Я знаю, что можно зайти на страницу проекта Spring Boot, там в разделе Learn найти нужную версию бута, щелкнуть по ссылке "Reference Doc > Dependency versions" и на открывшейся [странице](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions) будут все зависимости и их версии.

Но мне хотелось бы разобраться, как определить версии, используя git репозиторий бута. Я нашел [файл сборки graddle](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/3.1.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/build.gradle), там какие-то версии есть, но я не уверен, то ли это. Например, там не ищется spring-security-core, spring-web и т.д.

В общем, хочу разобраться как, имея на руках pom, сгенерированный на start.spring.io

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0-M1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

...

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

понять через git репозиторий бута, какие именно зависимости входят в spring-boot-starter-security, spring-boot-starter-web и какие у этих зависимостей версии.